# bad normal smoothing in blender versions > 2.91.2

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh, eevee-render-engine, normals

im not even sure how to word this let alone search the blender bug reporter for every trace of the word "normal"
but any smooth shaded low poly mesh in any blender version greater then 2.91.2 suffers from this
[image: left is blender 1.92.1, right is 3.1.2]

left is blender 1.92.1, right is 3.1.2
it looks like they tried to fix the weird fresnel effect that 2.91 had while simultaneously screwing up low poly modelers

my question is
is this a bug worth reporting?
or would i just get a "works as intended" despite it obviously not looking correct?

edit:
heres a blend file ive setup with a rotating camera to showcase the weirdness
https://pasteall.org/media/a/4/a49e1b88ac0e0bb8603987277f48f6ab.blend
just hit play on the timeline / space bar

Comment: More likely to be due to bad topology, but without seeing the underlying mesh in Edit mode it's impossible to say. I assume you've checked Auto Smooth Normals? (Green triangle > Normals > Auto Smooth.)

Comment: this mesh is just an icosphere with 1 subdivisions
and moved around a bit to bring out the funky sharp edges
and yes this is with the auto smooth normals set at 30
and either way same deal
if i can figure out how to upload a blend file
i can do and give an active example

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/ and paste a link to the file here.

Comment: thanks
added the example